# How do I set a grouped exposed filter of boolean fields in a view?

Tags: views, entities, search

I have a view with fields used as filters and exposed to user in a dropdown.
They are "grouped" in the filter section. These fields are boolean.

I can't get them to work together. It's working if I set a single one which "starts with" O or 1. As soon as a add a second condition, there is no result.

A wonder if there is any rule to concatenate the values of the filters (like 0,1,0,0 or 0010) but none of my shoots in the dark made it.

In other words, how do I make combined boolean exposed filters to work ?

Comment: I don't believe Grouped Filters do what you think they do. Grouped Filters are used to **group multiple values of a single field into one displayed value to the end user**. They are **not** used to group the values from multiple fields into a single filter.

An example would be if I had a number field, let's call it *Rating*, that allowed entering values from 1 to 10.

Normally, if I'm using an Exposed, dropdown filter for the field, this would be output to the user as a select list, with 10 separate options: 1, 2, 3, etc, 10.

Comment: However, if I use the grouped option, I can group these values together to form a different select list. It may be that I want to display all *Low Ratings* as one select option (anything 4 and below), all *Average Ratings* as a second option (values 5-8), and *Exceptional Ratings* (values 9 and 10) as a third option.

As you can imagine, your examples for a boolean field wouldn't make much sense.. There's no reason to have a filter option that is met if the field's value is False or True or False or False.